# How to show text on an image? (code is in question)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to learn coding in my freetime and have run into an issue. I am trying to have 'contact info' to be a on hover on profile picture so that it shows a way to contact me via phone, email, and shows my name. I'm hoping someone can help with this please.

Cut most of the HTML code in the process to allow post

```js
var infoDivs = document.getElementsByClassName ('infoDivs');
var contactInfoDiv = document.getElementById('contactInfo');

function displayInfo(index) {
    for (var i = 0; i < infoDivs.length; i++) {
        infoDivs[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    infoDivs[index].style.display = 'block';
}

function showcontactInfo() {
    contactInfoDiv.style.display = 'block'
}

function hidecontactInfo() {
    contactInfoDiv.style.display = 'none'
}



//line 12-18 is what should be my issue? Otherwise line 2? //
```

```css
html, body  {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-family: "verdana";
}

body {
    background-image: url('https://imgur.com/GfUxQA7.jpg');
    padding: 10px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 35px;
}

h2 {
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

header {
    margin: 20px;
    height: 20%;
}

header img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-width: 2px;
}

header p {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#main {
    position: relative;
    height: 70%;
}

#navlist {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 25%;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    
}

#navlist li {
    height: 18%;
}

#navlist li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

#infoContainer {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 10%;
    left: 25%;
    height: 90%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.infoDivs {
    display: none;
    margin: 20px;
}

.infoDivs h2 {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#bioDiv {
    display: block;
}

#contactInfo {
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    top: 30%
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3vw;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {

    #navList {
        font-size: 15px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    #infoContainer {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
}

    @media (max-width: 400px) {
        
        h1 {
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        header img {
            width: 50px;
            right: 5px;
        }

        #navList {
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS for my webpage.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>My webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="Javascript html.js"></script>
    <header>
        <img onmouseover='showcontactInfo()' onmouseout='hidecontactInfo()' src='Profile.jpg' alt="Profile picture"> <!--This is what line im having issue with i think?-->
        <h1>My Webpage</h1>
        <p>Welcome to my webpage where you can learn about me!</p>
</header>
<div id='main'>
    <ul id='navlist'>
        <li onclick='displayInfo(0)'>Bio</li>
        <li onclick='displayInfo(1)'>Education</li>
        <li onclick='displayInfo(2)'>Work</li>
        <li onclick='displayInfo(3)'>Projects</li>
        <li onclick='displayInfo(4)'>Interests</li>
        
    </ul>
    <div id='infoContainer'>
        <div id='bioDiv' class='infoDivs'>
            <h2>Bio</h2>
            <p>Here is a little about myself and my background.</p>
            <p>Hello my name is Antoly, I'm currently learning coding (HTML5, CSS, and Javascript) and teaching myself Italian language in my free time and attending school to become a Information Technology Network Specialist</p>
        </div>
        <div id='educationDiv' class='infoDivs'>
            <h2>Education</h2>
            <p>Here is some info about my schooling and courses that I've taken.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='contactInfo'> <!-- This is what I want to show my info when you put your mouse over my picture-->
    <p>Antoly Borshkev</p>
    <p>helloworld@gmail.com</p>
    <p>1111111111</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wasn't aware it wasn't supposed to be. I've only been learning for a couple weeks in my spare time. I have three different documents in Visual Code studio. HTML, CSS, and Javascript and they link together.

Comment: @brk - Are you perhaps thinking of [`<head />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head)? Having html inside of a [`<header />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header) seems perfectly reasonable to me...

Comment: PS: never use inline `on*` JavaScript attributes, same as you hopefully don't use inline `style` attributes. CSS and JS should be in their respective files or tags. Use addEventListener instead.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed `;` after `top: 30%;` in CSS `#contactInfo` class

```js
var infoDivs = document.getElementsByClassName ('infoDivs');
var contactInfoDiv = document.getElementById('contactInfo');

function displayInfo(index) {
    for (var i = 0; i < infoDivs.length; i++) {
        infoDivs[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    infoDivs[index].style.display = 'block';
}

function showcontactInfo() {
    contactInfoDiv.style.display = 'block'
}

function hidecontactInfo() {
    contactInfoDiv.style.display = 'none'
}



//line 12-18 is what should be my issue? Otherwise line 2? //
```

```css
html, body  {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-family: "verdana";
}

body {
    background-image: url('https://imgur.com/GfUxQA7.jpg');
    padding: 10px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 35px;
}

h2 {
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

header {
    margin: 20px;
    height: 20%;
}

header img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-width: 2px;
}

header p {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#main {
    position: relative;
    height: 70%;
}

#navlist {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 25%;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    
}

#navlist li {
    height: 18%;
}

#navlist li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

#infoContainer {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 10%;
    left: 25%;
    height: 90%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.infoDivs {
    display: none;
    margin: 20px;
}

.infoDivs h2 {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#bioDiv {
    display: block;
}

#contactInfo {
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    top: 30%; /* missed ; */
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3vw;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {

    #navList {
        font-size: 15px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    #infoContainer {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
}

    @media (max-width: 400px) {
        
        h1 {
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        header img {
            width: 50px;
            right: 5px;
        }

        #navList {
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS for my webpage.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>My webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="Javascript html.js"></script>
    <header>
        <img onmouseover='showcontactInfo()' onmouseout='hidecontactInfo()' src='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/taykG37GWDgY-FGkdogDvsHSJMUGRMvkuVRT6yR-5UNkKvGRKeRlpGYXlslocOcS0txlfUdGW59JGtzADknxbMqnh6AtVCv9EXyB8nHp80YsRNA0Yw=w100-h50-n-l50-sg-rj' alt="Profile picture"> <!--This is what line im having issue with i think?-->
        <h1>My Webpage</h1>
        <p>Welcome to my webpage where you can learn about me!</p>
</header>
<div id='main'>
    <ul id='navlist'>
        <li onclick='displayInfo(0)'>Bio</li>
        <li onclick='displayInfo(1)'>Education</li>
        <li onclick='displayInfo(2)'>Work</li>
        <li onclick='displayInfo(3)'>Projects</li>
        <li onclick='displayInfo(4)'>Interests</li>
        
    </ul>
    <div id='infoContainer'>
        <div id='bioDiv' class='infoDivs'>
            <h2>Bio</h2>
            <p>Here is a little about myself and my background.</p>
            <p>Hello my name is Antoly, I'm currently learning coding (HTML5, CSS, and Javascript) and teaching myself Italian language in my free time and attending school to become a Information Technology Network Specialist</p>
        </div>
        <div id='educationDiv' class='infoDivs'>
            <h2>Education</h2>
            <p>Here is some info about my schooling and courses that I've taken.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='contactInfo'> <!-- This is what I want to show my info when you put your mouse over my picture-->
    <p>Antoly Borshkev</p>
    <p>helloworld@gmail.com</p>
    <p>1111111111</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So if this is a typo, You shouldn't answer the question instead you should vote to close it in *Not reproducible or was caused by a typo* category.

Comment: wasn't aware of such rule...my bad...but I don't see a good reason to select in close vote dialog...

Comment: Hi Vanowm, when plugging it back into Visual code it doesn't show on hover part, Is it possible I'm doing something wrong on my part?